# RStudio enters debug mode for every function error - how can I stop it?

Tags: r, debugging, rstudio

I've been using RStudio for years, and this has never happened to me before. For some reason, every time a function throws an error, RStudio goes into debug mode (I don't want it to). Even after using undebug() on a single function.

```
> undebug(http.get)
Warning message:
In undebug(fun) : argument is not being debugged
> x = http.get(country = 'KE')

http --timeout=60 get "http://foo@bar.com/observation?country=KE" > freshobs.json </dev/null
Error in fromJSON(file = "freshobs.json") : unexpected character 'O'

Error in el[["product_name"]] : subscript out of bounds
Called from: grepl(el[["product_name"]], pattern = "json:", fixed = T)
Browse[1]> Q
```

Any function I use that breaks causes debug mode to start - which is pretty annoying because it opens up a source viewer and takes you away from your code. Anybody know how to stop this functionality?
This happens when the 'Use debug mode only when my code contains errors' check box in Preferences is and is not checked.

Thanks!

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I tried fixing this issue by putting `options(error = NULL)` in my `.Rprofile`, but this did not work.

What did work was to go to the ["Debug" -> "On Error" menu and select "Message only"](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/205612627-Debugging-with-RStudio#stopping-when-an-error-occurs). This effectively is the same as setting `options(error = NULL)`, but it is persistent across restarts.

[image: RStudio menu]

Answer (score 2):

Well, I think I sort of fixed it. No idea how this happened, but in Rstudio, running

```
> options()$error # returned:
 (function () 
{
    .rs.breakOnError(FALSE)
})()
```

Where as in the same thing returned NULL when running R from terminal. --> I ran:

```
options(error=NULL)
```

That fixes the problem - but only temporarily. When I quit and restart Rstudio, the code needs to be run again. Will update when I find a way to change the default... Cheers.

Comment: I don't think that is the default in rstudio, at least not for me. do you have something in your r profile

Comment: I don't think it's the default either (seeing as this problem only appeared now) - somehow it got changed.

Comment: You could define `options(error = stop)`. `options(error = recover)` can also be useful.

Comment: Definitely does appear to be default for me in RStudio (v1.0.12) on macOS

Comment: I think this happen to me after: running a code block with an error in a `.Rmd` file. Clicking `traceback` which changes `getOption("error")`. Then my session crashed due to some C++ code. I am running Windows with Rstudio version Version 1.1.383. Running`options(error = NULL)` and closing a session solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing worked for me: I had a function that when I run kept on debugging.

The **solution** for me was (with caution pls): `Debug (menü) -> clear All Breakpoints ...`

Answer (score 0):

I [reset my RStudio Desktop preferences](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200534577-Resetting-RStudio-Desktop-s-State) and the issue went away.

Note that the `options()$error` return value after this reset is:

```
(function () 
{
    .rs.recordTraceback(TRUE, 5, .rs.enqueueError)
})()
```

The value before this change was per [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29019002/revisions)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in RStudio Cloud. It was solved by choosing a different version of R. 
I was using R3.6.0 and changed it to R3.5.3 (the option in in the upper right corner). It refreshed the console and the debugging stopped. And then R3.6.0 was again fine.
Cheers.